# Как написать на jQuery удаление элементов

Tags: jquery

Не работает удаление созданных элементов.

```
    $('.smallphoto').bind('click', function(e) {
        $('<DIV id="background" class="fullphoto" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 100; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #AAAAAA;"><DIV id="container" class="fullphoto" style="position: absolute; margin: 0 auto;"><IMG class="fullphoto" src="images/125462-2000x1174.jpg" style="z-index: 101;"></DIV></DIV>').appendTo('body');
    });
    $('.fullphoto').bind('click', function(e) {
        $('.fullphoto').detach();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
$('.fullphoto').bind('click', function(e) {
    $('.fullphoto').detach();
});
```

на

```
$('.fullphoto').live('click', function(e) {
    $('.fullphoto').detach();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо использовать

```
$('.fullphoto').remove();
```